# Timer refreshing all updatepanels to refresh

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, updatepanel

I have a single timer in my html and 3 updatepanels, i want to refresh a specific updatepanel and not the 2 others. However the timer is causing all updatepanels to refresh for some reason. This is my updatepanel code that i want to refresh:

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:Timer runat="server" id="UpdateTimer" interval="2000" ontick="function" />

 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelMain" runat="server" updatemode="Conditional">
            <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger controlid="UpdateTimer" eventname="Tick" />
            </Triggers>
            <ContentTemplate>
```

And the other updatepanels look like this **without** the triggers:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelDiag" runat="server">
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelUi" runat="server">
```

However they are still updated, any idea why?

Comment: Place the Timer in the UpdatePanel you want to refresh.

Comment: That still refreshes all other panels

Comment: Maybe stupid question.. but could it be that your other 2 panels are inside the UpdatePanelMain?

Comment: They are not...